# New design: "Vote to close" box layout is broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The "exact duplicate" etc. labels have too much vertical space, which makes them look as though they are associated with the previous description rather than the one that follows. The culprit seems to be the `.cp {height: 50px;}` rule applied to the label.

Comment: i'm looking into it.

Comment: the fix should be live now, please verify.

Comment: @Jin: Sadly, due to the increased rep thresholds, I can no longer access the "vote to close" box to verify.

Comment: @Jin: I'm still seeing a lot of extra space between the title and body of the close reasons.

Comment: @Jin, @Jeff: Actually, I just realized, it's fine on the main site, but still broken on meta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pushed the fix, it will be in the next deployment.